# Declaring backgrounds in CSS in one line

Tags: css

This is my code: 
`background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff,#e0e0e0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff,#e0e0e0);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#fff,#e0e0e0);`

is there any way of putting it in one line, its giving me eslint errors.

Comment: Use Autoprefixer.

Answer (score 0):

You can (for the most part) just write `background: linear-gradient(#fff,#e0e0e0);`.

This is compatible with:

```
Firefox 10+
Opera 11.6+
Chrome 26+
IE 10+
```

The vendor prefixes are only required for very early browsers (circa Internet Explorer 9). As of this post, [only 0.6%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_image_gradient_linear-gradient) of web users are using a browser that would apply the style with the vendor prefix but not with the shorthand above. And for what it's worth, ShouldIPrefix [*recommends*](http://shouldiprefix.com/#gradients) not prefixing linear gradients.

If you want to support very old browsers, you must use the vendor prefixes. If not, the shorthand is perfectly acceptable.